# Div upon div scrolling while reach to bottom or top

Tags: html, css

I have 2 DIVS, one inside the other.
both are scrollable.

When I scroll the "inside div" (the green one, in the attatched file), and reach to the bottom of the DIV, it start to scroll the DIV beneath.
how can I disable the DIV beneath to scroll, only when I scroll the top DIV?

```
<div class="container">

<div class="neneathDiv">
  blah blah <br>blah blah <br>blah blah <br>blah blah <br>blah blah <br>blah blah <br>blah blah <br>blah blah <br>blah blah <br>blah blah <br>blah blah <br>blah blah <br>blah blah <br>blah blah <br>blah blah <br>blah blah <br>blah blah <br>blah blah <br>blah blah <br>blah blah <br>blah blah <br>blah blah <br>blah blah <br>blah blah <br>blah blah <br>blah blah <br>blah blah <br>blah blah <br>blah blah <br>blah blah <br>blah blah <br>blah blah <br>blah blah <br>blah blah <br>blah blah <br>blah blah <br>blah blah <br>blah blah <br>blah blah <br>blah blah <br>blah blah <br>blah blah <br>blah blah <br>blah blah <br>blah blah <br>blah blah <br>blah blah <br>blah blah <br>blah blah <br>blah blah <br>blah blah <br>blah blah <br>blah blah <br>blah blah <br>blah blah <br>blah blah <br>blah blah <br>blah blah <br>blah blah <br>blah blah <br>blah blah <br>blah blah <br>blah blah <br>blah blah <br>blah blah <br>blah blah <br>blah blah <br>blah blah <br>blah blah <br>blah blah <br>blah blah <br>blah blah <br>blah blah <br>blah blah <br>blah blah <br>blah blah <br>blah blah <br>blah blah <br>blah blah <br>blah blah <br>blah blah <br>blah blah <br>blah blah <br>blah blah <br>blah blah <br>blah blah <br>blah blah <br>blah blah <br>blah blah <br>blah blah <br>blah blah <br>blah blah <br>blah blah <br>blah blah <br>blah blah <br>blah blah <br>

  <div class="topDiv">
  blah blah <br>blah blah <br>blah blah <br>blah blah <br>blah blah <br>blah blah <br>blah blah <br>blah blah <br>blah blah <br>blah blah <br>blah blah <br>blah blah <br>blah blah <br>blah blah <br>blah blah <br>blah blah <br>blah blah <br>blah blah <br>blah blah <br>blah blah <br>blah blah <br>blah blah <br>blah blah <br>blah blah <br>blah blah <br>blah blah <br>blah blah <br>blah blah <br>blah blah <br>blah blah <br>blah blah <br>blah blah <br>blah blah <br>blah blah <br>blah blah <br>blah blah <br>blah blah <br>blah blah <br>blah blah <br>blah blah <br>blah blah <br>blah blah <br>blah blah <br>blah blah <br>blah blah <br>blah blah <br>blah blah <br>blah blah <br>blah blah <br>blah blah <br>blah blah <br>blah blah <br>blah blah <br>blah blah <br>blah blah <br>blah blah <br>blah blah <br>blah blah <br>blah blah <br>blah blah <br>blah blah <br>blah blah <br>blah blah <br>blah blah <br>blah blah <br>blah blah <br>blah blah <br>blah blah <br>blah blah <br>blah blah <br>blah blah <br>blah blah <br>blah blah <br>blah blah <br>blah blah <br>blah blah <br>blah blah <br>blah blah <br>blah blah <br>blah blah <br>blah blah <br>blah blah <br>blah blah <br>blah blah <br>blah blah <br>blah blah <br>blah blah <br>blah blah <br>blah blah <br>blah blah <br>blah blah <br>blah blah <br>blah blah <br>blah blah <br>blah blah <br>blah blah <br>
</div>

</div>
```

```
   .container{background-color: blue; }
.topDiv{background-color: green; width: 300px; position: absolute; top: 0; 
          right:0; height: 100%; z-index: 99; overflow: auto;}
.neneathDiv{background-color: red; height: 100px;  height: 100%; overflow: auto;}
```

[Here's a Demo of my problem](https://jsfiddle.net/s4yzpwk9/)

Comment: How about closing second div ? You did not close it.

Comment: What @ElDanielo says. I've closed it for you and added thescript of vincent below.

http://jsbin.com/kipicijule/edit?html,output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made an example, you will need to have jquery added in the page :

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('.topDiv').on('scroll', function() {
        if($(this).scrollTop() + $(this).innerHeight() >= $(this)[0].scrollHeight) {
            $('body').addClass("hide");
        } else {
            $('body').removeClass("hide");
        }
    });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/s4yzpwk9/8/

Answer (score 1):

Can you use javascript (and jQuery) ?

If yes, here's a solution :

[See this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s4yzpwk9/2/)

```
$(".topDiv").bind( 'mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function ( e ) {
                    //Get the original Event
                    var e0 = e.originalEvent,
                    //Hold the movement of the scroll 
                    delta = e0.wheelDelta ;
                    //If it's negative add -30 for each step or 30 if is positive
                    this.scrollTop += ( delta < 0 ? 1 : -1 ) * 30;
                    //Apply the scroll only for the element with the 
                    //handler      
                    e.preventDefault();
                    //Prevent the normal event
                });
```

See original post here : 
[With jQuery, how can I prevent the page from scroll when reaching the bottom of a scrollable div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22694503/with-jquery-how-can-i-prevent-the-page-from-scroll-when-reaching-the-bottom-of)

Answer (score 0):

try this function hope it will help you

```
$( '.topDiv' ).bind( 'mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function ( e ) {
var e0 = e.originalEvent,
    delta = e0.wheelDelta || -e0.detail;

this.scrollTop += ( delta < 0 ? 1 : -1 ) * 30;
e.preventDefault();
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct behaviour as your page is deeper than the viewport. You can use JS to capture the scroll event and prevent it from working on a particular element or you can structure your page to account for this.

One option may be to restrict the height of the `body` and then hide the overflow.

```
body, html, .container {padding:0; margin:0; height:100%; max-height:100%;}
.container {overflow: hidden;}
```

Like this: https://jsfiddle.net/s4yzpwk9/6/

Comment: I like your answer but now you have a fixed container in the right and i guess it's not what he wants . But i do like it i will use that thanks .